# Trying to run Mac OSX Mountain Lion in a Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to run OS X Mountain Lion in a virtual machine inside Windows 7. 
I have set virtualization to true in the BIOS and I have successfully virtualized Windows 8.
Are there any other settings to change in the BIOS?

I got the InstallESD.dmg from the Apple Store and when I try to run it in a virtual machine, it brings up a command line with < SHELL> and I can type help, exit, etcetra and there are many commands, however when I type exit to get out of the < SHELL> Command line, it brings up a screen with several boot options. I click continue and it goes back to the < SHELL> Command line screen.

I am using VirtualBox by Oracle to run virtual machines, and I have set all the settings in VirtualBox for MAC OS X.

If you could help with this matter, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but per the OS X EULA you may only run an OS X Mountain Lion virtual machine inside OS X Mountain Lion running on an Apple computer. The OS X installer is protected against running in non-Apple environments. Since this is all a legal grey area and involves more hacking than specific problem solving, Hackintosh questions are considered off topic for Super User. You might be able to find better help in specialized forums.

Comment: @slhck There are many options such as iATKOS_ML2 which allows people to run Mac OS X inside other operating systems. Seriously, if Apple didn't want people to virtualize their software they shouldn't set it so you can only make IOS games on a Mac. Anyway, I'm not even making a Hackintosh, I am virtualizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install MacOS 10.8.2 Intel in VirtualBox.docx:

https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=4CD1B952A2640E72&resid=4CD1B952A2640E72%211040&app=Word

Install MacOS 10.8.2 Intel in VirtualBox.pdf :

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=4CD1B952A2640E72&id=4CD1B952A2640E72%21233#cid=4CD1B952A2640E72&id=4CD1B952A2640E72%211039